# Rewrite default Drupal view programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Say we have a defaul view (i.e hardcoded), provided by Views module , for example "taxonomy/term/%"

Now, I'd like to make some modification to that view programmatically, through an installation profile

Normally I use Features module for such work, but Features does not support default views.

Please advise how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: What aspect of the view do you want to alter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`hook_views_default_views_alter`](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_default_views_alter)

```
function MODULE_views_default_views_alter(&$views) {
  if (isset($views['taxonomy_term'])) {
    $views['taxonomy_term']->set_display('default');
    $views['taxonomy_term']->display_handler->set_option('title', 'Categories');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Views theme information. There is a link you can use to find out what you should name your views (Its called "Theme Information") copy the name of the particular part of the view you would like to hardcode and paste it as a new file in your template's directory. You can use a folder (I usually name it views) to separate these files from others in the template. You'll need to refresh your cache to see the changes once you've created the new template file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [hook_views_default_views_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views_alter/7)

Here's a good example:
[enter link description here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1014774)